# Is it possible to use 'systemctl' in pod?

Tags: kubernetes, centos7, dbus, systemctl

I made an image using dockerfile. And I created pod from the image that I created.
But an error has occurred. When I get a shell to pod and used 'systemctl', I got a D-bus error. How can I solve this problem?

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically can't use `systemctl` in Docker, since containers don't run the `systemd` daemon.  This is tricky to run in Docker itself, and the couple of workarounds that could make it go are difficult-to-impossible to express in Kubernetes.

You should come up with some other way to run your process.  Usually a container will only run a single service, and so instead of starting it via a systemd unit file you can just run the service directly; your Dockerfile might end with something like

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/myserviced", "--foreground"]
```

Comment: --foreground: unrecognized service